# Is it possible to save a dynamic path to Matlab search path or pathdef.m?

Tags: matlab

I want to add a path like

```
getenv('userprofile'),'\Dropbox\Matlab\example1'
```

to the Matlab pathdef.m file. The system variable `%userprofile%` will change from computer to computer.

Adding the phrase to pathdef.m will not work though.

Is there a way to add a dynamic path to the Matlab search path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `up = getenv('userprofile')` to get the user profile path environment variable. Then use `addpath(up)` to add it to the path, or change the current directory to it using `cd(up)`.

Your example with a subfolder, being `'\Dropbox\Matlab\example1'`, would work like this:

```
up = getenv('userprofile');
sub = '\Dropbox\Matlab\example1';
addpath([up sub]) % or cd(__)
```

This works, because both `up` and `sub` are strings of characters (they are of class `char`). They can be concatenated using `[up sub]`, so they form a longer string of characters, being the path to your folder of choice.

For ease, this can be put in `startup.m`, so every time MATLAB starts your directory of choice is added to the path.